# Is it bad for Android phones to install and delete one app multiple times?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Can OS become slower by installing and uninstalling an app multiple times?
Can this process make any harm to system, or is it safe to do it?

Comment: Nice question! I do it a lot since I don't want to use an antivirus and I install it every 2 weeks, scan and uninstall it again. I suppose though that if you are using some cleaning app like cleanMaster, then you will be fine.

Comment: Please see this recent article (2017/02/10) - [10 most useless apps and games for Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/most-useless-apps-android-749163). Most prominent, but specifically named in the list: Clean Master (along with quote-Booster apps, Anti-Virus apps, and Task Killers-unquote)

Comment: @wbogacz These words are golden. I wish there were more people to say that.

Comment: @wbogacz I don't disagree that clean master does not boost your phone. It deletes unused files though. I also use it the same way I use the antivirus. once every month install - scan/clean - delete

Comment: @papakias 
Thank you very much! Thanks to wbogacz and Death Mask Salesman too!

But since its one app that is being installed and uninstalled, shouldn't those unused files after uninstalling that application start being used again by same application after I install it again?

Comment: I@MiDZiiii If it's only one application they will be used again. The only thing that might stay is install logs if any.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is totally fine. If you think your phone is slow clean the junk files or the cache using some good app like clean master and after cleaning everything uninstall it so that it doesn't run in background. Install it again when you think your phone has become slow and uninstall it again. Best way is keep a backup of the app so that you don't need to download it again and again.

Comment: Clean Master is garbage and malware, stay away.

Comment: It might be useful to read this latest (2018/11/26) [Android Central](https://www.androidcentral.com/eight-android-apps-2-billion-downloads-are-committing-ad-click-fraud) blog report about "Clean Master" and its ad-click actions.